# Log4j2 For Spark. where is the log4j default properties file?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, spark-streaming, log4j2

Where can i find the default log4j configuration files for worker and driver?

1) Currently Spark is logging Executor/Worker(stdout/stderr) level logs to **Work** folder and Driver level logs to logs folder.

where can i find this configuraiton.?

I am trying to to use Log4j2 for spark instead of log4j. I am trying to get the default properties file so that i can replicate few thing from there to log4j2 properties XML.

2) Also, Is it possible to modify log4j properties on a currently running job?

Answer (score 0):

Under  **/conf/log4j.properties.template** . **Rename** the file to **log4j.properties** and make your configuration changes.

Comment: I didn't see Work or Logs folder mentioned in log4j.properties.How log4j is coming to know to write the logs to those folders?

Comment: log4j.appender.file.File=c:\\logigng.log    Add the appender into your log4j file. 
for more info abt log4j , find it here https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Comment: you may need to have seperate log4j properties to your nodes . Again it is subjected to the cluster manager you are using.

Comment: These answers all seem to be targeted at Log4j 1. He specifically said he wants to use Log4j 2. The link provided above seems to point to a standard log4j1 configuration with a console appender and a rolling file appender. You can find examples of those on the Log4j 2 web site. Yes, Log4j 2 will allow you to reconfigure on in a running job if you add monitorInterval=nn to the Configuration element.

Comment: Where can i find the default log4j configuration files for worker and driver?.....  My answer is related to this

Comment: @AKC I have the exact same issue here. My logs are being send to spark/work instead of the configured log location